# Access static pictures from "login/" returns 401

Tags: nginx, gerrit

I have a pretty "standard" Gerrit setup on a Debian 11 VM:

- Gerrit is installed under `/opt/gerrit/` with a specific `gerrit` user used to execute the software; this user have the correct rights to access the path; also the configuration is very basic

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = /opt/git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://192.168.10.101/git/
    serverId = xxxxx
[container]
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
    user = gerrit
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
[index]
    type = lucene
[auth]
    type = LDAP
    gitBasicAuthPolicy = LDAP
[ldap]
...
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = true
[sendemail]
...
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8080/git/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

- nginx is installed from apt and it's configured basically as suggested by Gerrit docs

```
  listen 80;
  server_name git.mysite.com;

  location ^~ /git/ {
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  }
}
```

The setup works as expected, I was trying to add some customization to the login page but I've found an error that I can't quite narrow down.
I've added a simple "GerritSiteHeader.html" page, defined as:

```
<div>
    <img src="static/logo.png" height="150" width="415"/>
</div>
```

The "logo.png" is stored under /opt/gerrit/static/ with permission assigned to "gerrit" user.

When I access the login page from `http://192.168.10.101/git/login`, the logo is correclty loaded, but if instead I'm using an URL like `http://192.168.10.101/git/login/` (with the added '/' at the end, which happens e.g. when clicking "Sign in" link inside gerrit, for example `git/login/%2F%2Fq%2Fstatus%3Aopen%2B-is%3Awip`), the logo is not displayed, from browser console I see "Error 401 Unauthorized"

I've checked the configurations of nginx and proxy pass but I haven't found anything, I'm not used to this kind of configuration. For what I see the main difference from browser console is that with `git/login/`URL, there are two GET request, referring to "login" and the logo.png itself, using instead `git/login` triggers only one GET request to "login" only.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, even by only pointing to more documentation or information!
Grazie :)

Comment: This feels more like a configuration issue rather than a programming issue.

Comment: @ewokx should I post this on Server Fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by trial and error. Apparently there is something going on between nginx and Gerrit with the resolution of the URL, I've solved this by specifing a full path to my logo:
`<img src="/git/static/logo.png" height="150" width="415"/>`

This allows the correct loading of the image independetly from the URL used